# having problems with Routing, password validation via a emailed link

Tags: php, slim

Im trying to create a password reset procedure.  The user will receive an email, with a link. The link consist of route with userid and reset key
The user need to enter 2 password  with validation, password the same, before the form will be submitted. Using vlucas/valitron validation.

The problem im having is that I cant pass values the userid and reset key in the route, the only way I got it to work is to sacrifice the password validation routines.

The link in the email    http://...../auth/reset/1/c15ec3a77934f0beda55

The route.

```
$this->get('/reset/{_userid}/{_key}', App\Controllers\Auth\ForgotController::class . ':reset1')->setName('auth.reset');
$this->post('/reset', App\Controllers\Auth\ForgotController::class . ':reset2');
```

The twig file.

```
<form action="{{ route('auth.reset') }}" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="{{ csrf.key }}" value="{{ csrf.token }}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="{{ data1.userid }}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{ data1.key }}">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control{{ errors.password ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="password">

                                {% if errors.password %}
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ errors.password | first }}
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control{{ errors.password_confirmation ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="password_confirmation">

                                {% if errors.password_confirmation %}
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ errors.password_confirmation | first }}
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change password</button>
  </form>
```

The functions

```
public function reset1(Request $request, Response $response, DB $db, Flash $flash, $_userid=null, $_key=null) {

        $userinfo = [
            'userid' => $_userid,
            'key' => $_key
        ];
        return $this->view->render($response, 'auth/reset.twig', compact('userinfo'));
    }

  public function reset2(Request $request, Response $response) {
       $data = $this->validatePassword($request);
       // do more stuff
   }

protected
            function validatePassword(Request $request) {
        return $this->validate($request, [
                    'password' => ['required'],
                    'password_confirmation' => ['required', ['equals', 'password']],
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the 3. route argument? [See here](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/routing.html)

Comment: Hi Odan, im using vlucas/valitron and it checks that both passwords are the same before it submit the data, if I put in one password and click submit it should refresh the route and display the error 2nd password not found, password not the same.

im getting this error... Uncaught League\Container\Exception\NotFoundException: Unable to resolve a value for parameter (_userid) in the function/method (reset1)

the route changed to this,,, it droped the _userid and key
http://......./auth/reset

Comment: This works....

http://…/auth/reset?_userid=example&_key=examplekey

$this->get('/reset', App\Controllers\Auth\ForgotController::class . ':reset1')


 public function reset1(Request $request, Response $response)
{
    
    $userinfo = $request->getQueryParams()

    //...
}